# How Can I show attribute variation description with woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce under Products > Attributes > [Name of Attribute] > Add New [Attribute Variation] there is a section titled Description with the text.
And under it is written The description is not prominent by default; however, some themes may show it."

I'd like to show it in my theme directly below the attribute variation in the Additional Information tab. I would appreciate an information on how to do this please
I don't think my theme supports this but is another there a way I can display it?
Thanks

Comment: This is a question for your theme developers I'm afraid. We can't help you with the information you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your single product template it will show attribute description there. Please use some hook to display this in additional tab and put below code.

```
$values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], array( 'fields' =>  'all' ) );
if( $values ){
    echo '<dl>';
        foreach ( $values as $term ){
            echo '<dh>' . $term->name.' </dh>';
            echo '<dd>' . term_description( $term->term_id ) . '</dd>';
        }
    echo '</dl>';
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks... I added it to my single-product.js file and it didn't work or did I add it to the wrong file? Please help

Comment: have to add it to php file. Find in your active theme there is a folder of templates for woocommerce, there you can find the single-product.php or may be with some similar name.

Comment: Please read some more document for creating woocommerce template into theme.