# Shortcode to display product attribute terms description when a variation is selected in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm looking for a way to create a wordpress shortcode to display the terms descriptions of the selected attributes for the woocommerce variable products.

For example on a T-shirt with color variation and logo variation
I would like to be able to display the description of the 2 terms : Of the selected color and the selected logo one below the other .

I relied on this code to understand how to create a shortcode :
[Shortcode that display all product attributes set for a WooCommerce product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215522/shortcode-that-display-all-product-attributes-set-for-a-woocommerce-product)

And on this code to retrieve and display attribute descriptions but I can't seem to combine the two.
[How Can I show attribute variation description with woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60373045/how-can-i-show-attribute-variation-description-with-woocommerce)

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

LeoM

Comment: By default woocommerce shows variation description when its selected. See description field in variaton - https://barn2.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Add-WooCommerce-product-variation-description-820x633.jpg

Answer (score 0):

With this code I manage to display all the descriptions of the variations used on the product :

```
add_shortcode( 'woo_attribute_descriptions', 'woo_attribute_descriptions_shortcode' );
function woo_attribute_descriptions_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $product;
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array('product_id' => $product->get_id(),), 
    $atts, 'woo_attribute_descriptions' );
    $product_id = $atts['product_id'];
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    $output = '';
    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
        $name = wc_attribute_label( $attribute->get_name() );
        $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, $attribute->get_name(), array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $output .= '<p>' . wpautop($term->description) . '</p>';
        }
    }
return $output;}
```

How to display only the descriptions of the selected variations?

Thanks!